# Connect a Jaeger agent to a collector running in Openshift

Tags: jaeger

I am having problems pointing a jaeger agent to a collector running in openshift.

I am able to browse my OCP collector endpoint doing this:

```
 https://mycollectoropenshift.com:443
```

My jaeger agent Dockerfile currently looks like this

```
FROM centos:latest
EXPOSE 5775/udp 6831/udp 6832/udp 5778
COPY agent-linux /go/bin/

#CMD ["--collector.host-port=localhost:14267"]
#CMD ["--collector.host-port=https://mycollectoropenshift.com:443"]
CMD ["--collector.host-port=mycollectoropenshift.com:443"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/agent-linux"]
```

I get the expected result when i point my agent to a collector running locally per the first commented line.

I get the following error using the second uncommented CMD flag.

```
error":"dial tcp: address https://mycollectoropenshift.com:443: too many colons in address"
```

When i attempt the agent to the collector running on openshift, i get the error below

```
Failed to run the agent: listen tcp 10.100.120.221:443: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

I am able to successfully curl the collector endpoint by doing this

```
curl https://mycollectoropenshift.com:443
```

I get the following error when i attempt to curl the endpoint this way:

```
curl mycollectoropenshift.com:443
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I need help setting up a proper `--collector.host-port` flag that will connect to a collector running remotely behind an HTTPS protocol.

Comment: what is the backend datastore you are using with this jaeger setup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at the moment and you should definitely ask for this feature in the mailing list, Gitter or GitHub issue. The current assumption is that a clear TChannel connection can be made between the agent and collector(s), all being part of the same trusted network.

If you are using the Java, Node or C# client, my recommendation in your situation is to have your Jaeger Client to talk directly to the collector. Look for the env var `JAEGER_ENDPOINT` in the [Client Features](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.9/client-features/) documentation page.